# Do we call $\mathbb{Z}^n$ in $\mathbb{Z}^n\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{k_1}\oplus\dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{k_u}$ free part or torsion-free part?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Q1) Do we call $\mathbb{Z}^n$ in $G=\mathbb{Z}^n\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{k_1}\oplus\dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{k_u}$ the free part or torsion-free part?

Are both names acceptable?

Q2) How about for $R^n$ in $M=R^n\oplus R/(d_1)\oplus\dots R/(d_2)$ where $R$ is a PID? Is it correct to say that we can only call it the free part in this case, since $R^n$ may not be torsion-free?

Thanks.

Comment: A PID is, by definition, an integral domain, so doesn't have zero divisors. How can $R^n$ have torsion?

Comment: @lisyarus You are right indeed..

Comment: Over a PID, a finitely generated module is free iff it is torsion-free.